# android: admob InterstitialAd crash at loadAd

Tags: android, crash, admob, interstitial

I'm using InterstitialAd by Admob. My app crashes at "loadAd" only in the first time it's called, and it's not reproducible (it happens once in 100-200 runs less or more). the ad unit id is correct for sure. So if loadAd doesn't fail in the first time it's called, it won't fail at all at this run.

class member:

```
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
```

onCreate:

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));

mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        requestNewInterstitial();
        finish();
    }
});

requestNewInterstitial();
```

requestNewInterstitial method:

```
private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(getResources().getString(R.string.test_device))
                .build();

        if (adRequest == null) {
            return;
        }

        // HERE'S THE CRASH
        try {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The **catch** doesn't catch the crash of "loadAd".

**How can I catch it or at least cause it not to crash my app? I wish that when loadAd fails, no ad will be displayed.**

LOGCAT:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 in tid 27794 (AdWorker(Defaul)
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
```

I don't know if the last 2 lines are about this crash but the first one is for sure.

Comment: This is an error in a native C library. What device are you testing on?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes what happen is Ad does to get loaded into your buffer so when you try to call loadAd, it crashes 
onCreate:

```
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    // set the ad unit ID
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_id));

    AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    // Load ads into Interstitial Ads

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest2);

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            showInterstitial();
        }
    });
```

In the same class:

```
private void showInterstitial() {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so what's the solution? I'm sure that the crash is at the line of "loadAd" because I just printed a number before each line and when the crash happens, the number after the line of "loadAd" is never printed.

Comment: Try to follow the steps as i Showed you above, add the setAdListener. It should work. Also I'm not familiar with the Error that is in your Logcat, It may be problem that i mentioned, so try to do once.

Comment: ohh I got it! I'll try it hundreds of times and I'll let you know. thanks!

Comment: exactly when I wanted to say that it works meantime, it failed.. again at "loadAd" pffff

Comment: on which are you doing your testing?

Answer (score 0):

**Activtiy_m1.java**

```
public class Activity_m1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    InterstitialAd interstitial;
    Activity mactivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_m1);
        setTitle("ABCD");
        Advertise.displaym1(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            Advertise adv = new Advertise();
            adv.disp_adm1();
        finish();
    }
}
```

**Advertise.java**

```
public class Advertise {
    public static InterstitialAd interstitial;

    public static void displaym1(Context act) {
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(act);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2621588945556564/3343556333");
        AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest1);
    }
    public void disp_adm1() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded())
            interstitial.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what's the difference between this to how the firebase shows? except the static attitude..