# Interstitial Ads not loading any longer

Tags: android, admob

I had a code that successfully loaded Admob test Interstitial Ads, but suddenly, without changing anything it doesn't load them any longer.

This happened to me once before and it was because they had changed the unit id needed to show interstitial ads, but now as much as I look it looks that it hasn't been changed.

Maybe, it's just that google has his server for test interstitial Ads down, but I'd like to check.

This is the code that was working just about 30 minutes ago:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        this.interstitialAds = new InterstitialAd(this);

        this.interstitialAds.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");

        this.interstitialAds.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {

                canshowad = true;
                //interstitialAds.show();
                super.onAdLoaded();
            }
                   [...]
        });

        AdRequest adr = new AdRequest.Builder() .addTestDevice(myTestDevice).build();
        interstitialAds.loadAd(adr);
```

Now it doesn't matter how much I wait, onAdLoaded never fires, as a the interstitial ad is never loaded.

Ironically, I'm also displaying a banner and the banner displays nicely.

What could be happening?

Comment: Does your app is live and are you testing it in emulator?

Comment: It's live, testing it on phone device.

Comment: Please make sure you have completed the payment address info. If you are registered your first app than.

Comment: @Shubman Sejpal They are test ads, as far as I know there's nothing to pay.

Comment: Please try this :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43237197/6096821

Comment: Well, actually changing the Unit Id to the one shown there, displayed an ad, problem is it's not a test one, but well, it's clear that problem is that the id for test ads is no longer correct. I'll just wait for some days and contact them if it's not corrected.